# 'Save settings' (submit button) ISSET

Tags: plugins

How to check if submit button is pressed with these form parameters:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```

Comment: if the button is pressed, you will find its name in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

You question is not well explained, what you want to achieve, here is the suggestion,

you can add JS event ONClick into you submit button and define the JS function according to your goals, (for example you want to count submit button click)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
</script>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
   . 
   . 
   .
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Submit</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
 </form>
```